# How to use active class when login or Register link clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using one mvc 4 application where i used bootstrap class.Now i used one html helper class to check if any actionlink menu is clicked there it set class active.

Now the issue is with Navbar brand link and login and register link.

I can't use the same html helper class for these because it is having some extra properties used like below code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
```

Above first link is header which should be by default active.

and other one are login and register which should be active after clicked.

Comment: Are you wanting to add `class="active"` to say the 2nd link if you navigate to the `Register.cshtml` page?

Comment: Yes Stephen, I want that when login or register link is clicked then menu link should add active class.

Comment: You could put a value in `ViewBag` - say `ViewBag.ActiveLink = "registerLink"` (or `= "loginLink"`) and then use some a script that runs when the page loads - `$('#' + '@ViewBag.ActiveLink').addClass('active');`

Comment: As per your suggestion I tried to set Viewbag value in  jquery on register or login click event to set value but i am not able to set value in Viewbag. or you have some better solution then please share with me.

Comment: You don't set the `ViewBag` value in jquery (its server side code). You set it in the controllers GET method.

Comment: I used Viewbag value in controller when login button clicked it set the vIewbag value of login in login constructor and i used if condition to check viewbag if login then use this code:  @if (ViewBag.Link == "Login")
        {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class="active" })</li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
        } but still it is not working

Comment: I got it now instead of adding class inside Actionlink i used like @if (ViewBag.Link == "Login")
        {
                <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink"})</li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
        }

Comment: Now the second question is how to set class active for this @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

Comment: I got the solution for this on header name click will not change property for active as because it's just a header not the menu. For that directly applying class="active" in @Html.ActionLink.

Comment: I got the solution for navbar brand to assign to class active just used inside style:"color:white";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got some idea from internet which is first i created one @html helper class which is like below:

```html
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper,string text, string action, string controller)
        {
            var routeData = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
            var currentController = routeData["controller"];
            var currentAction = routeData["action"];

            if (String.Equals(action, currentAction as string,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            &&
            String.Equals(controller, currentController as string,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return new MvcHtmlString("<li class=\"active\">" + helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller) + "</li>");
            }
            return new MvcHtmlString("<li>" + helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller) + "</li>");
        }
```

Then i called this class in my menu links like below:

@Html.MenuLink("Home", "Index", "Home")

So after click on this link it is setting as active.
Thanks everyone for helped me.